# Model swift enum with associated value in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

How can I implement Swift's enum with associated values in objective C.

The use case is,

There are three states "None" "Open" "Closed".
"Open" and "Closed" need to have associated values (Positive Integers) with them.
Only one of the state can exists at a time. That is either "None" only or "Open" only or "Closed" only.

I can model this easily in swift with associated value. How can I model this in Objective C